# can't setup reverse proxy in golang with tcp tunnel in between

Tags: go, tunnel

i built reverse proxy by example i saw on internet:
stream.go

```
func StartStream(dst, src net.Conn) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        io.Copy(dst, src)

    }()

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        io.Copy(src, dst)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}

func RevProxy() {
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:1080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        bconn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:1086")
        go StartStream(bconn, conn)

    }
}
```

The RevProxy() works fine but when i'm trying to copy stream into tcp tunnel it won't work as it expected
i want something like this:

> (origin server --- dialer)listener -------- dialer(listener --- client)

listener.go

```
func handleConn(conn net.Conn) {
    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        bconn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:1086")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        StartStream(bconn, conn)
        bconn.Close()
    }

}

func Listener() {
    log.Print("start listening on 8080")
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for {
        conn, _ := l.Accept()
        go handleConn(conn)
    }
}
```

dialer.go

```
func Dialer() {
    log.Print("dialing 8080")
    //establishing tunnel
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Print("start listening on 1080")
    //start tcp listener on 1080
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:1080")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer l.Close()
    for {
        llconn, _ := l.Accept()
        //copy incoming from tcp listener to dialer at 8080 and vice versa
        go StartStream(conn, llconn)
    }

}
```

tried gorilla websocket but it didn't work

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means. I don't understand the attempted diagram here -- you need to show what happened, what went wrong, and what you expect to happen.